# In what way would Java's Thread.sleep would be useful here?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee

I am working on an existing Java EE Multi-threading application.

I am unable to understand this thing on to my Application. There is one thread named  `UserThread`, and in its `run` method's `while(true)` condition it reads data from a location and pushes the data to a Websocket. After that the Thread sleeps for 1000 seconds.

Why is this `Thread.sleep()` useful?

Comment: It actually sleeps for a minimum of 1000 seconds. It goes into a runnable state after that and it is up to the scheduler to get the thread going again

Comment: I would imagine to ensure that the data was transferred completely before moving on to the next task?

Comment: Do you have a code sample you can show us? Is it pulling information from a website, or just reading from a file on disk?

Comment: 1000 seconds or 1000 milliseconds?

Comment: Without a low level detail about your application, it is hard to tell why sleep() is used. Provide relevant code to walkthrough

Comment: In general programs , Thread.sleep() is a code smell. I have used it only in writing test cases - that too very very sparingly - when alternative approaches are overkill.

Comment: @envinyater A sleep cannot possibly have that effect. Only TCP knows when a transfer is complete.

Comment: I've used it as a guessing mechanism, but you are correct. Only TCP knows when it has finished. Sorry for the bad info!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like it's just being used to throttle the reads and/or writes to avoid sending too many requests at once.

Comment: In our Application there is a throttle Time set to 1000 milliseconds and the Thread sleeps for 1000 ms , so you mean to say that , requests will be sent every 1000 ms , rather than continuously checking ??

Comment: @PreethiJain - If it's already throttling elsewhere then I'm not sure what the `Thread.sleep()` is for. The point is that, if it didn't throttle, it would send requests as fast as possible and hammer the endpoint it's reading from or writing to. If the other end can't handle that, the constant flood of requests might bring it down or make it unusable to others. The throttle attempts to prevent that.

Answer (score 4):

It is emulating a timer, executing a task every x seconds, which is very bad practice. Consider switching to `java.util.Timer` or `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`:

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(
      new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
               // code
          }
      }, 0, 1000, TimeUnit.Milliseconds);
```

Comment: If it's being used as a primitive request throttle, then `Thread.sleep()` isn't too terrible. If one needs more accurate timing, the `ThreadPoolExecutor` is the way to go.

Comment: @Rob Hruska: `while(true)` + `sleep` smells like timed action to me.

Comment: It does to me, too. Just depends on how accurate his timing needs to be and how much he cares that the thread is just sitting there idle. `Thread.sleep()` is usually a kludge, but can get the job done sometimes.